# Ag-Grid 9 server side pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, ag-grid

I would like to do server side pagination with Ag-Grid, but I can't make next button enabled. I used the same method in a previous project and there it worked well, but with the new grid version it doesn't work.

My grid options look like this:

```
        gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            datasource: datasource,
            pagination: true,
            paginationPageSize: 8,
            rowModelType: 'pagination'
        };
```

And my datasource is this:

```
        datasource = {
            rowCount: -1,
            getRows: function (params) {
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl,
                    type: "post",
                    data: params
                });

                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    params.successCallback(response.Values, response.Count);
                });

                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    params.failCallback();
                });
            }
        };
```

I debugged my code many times, response.Count is 15 (I even tried to hardcode it, but it didn't help either) right now but I can't navigate to the 2nd page.
By the way if I comment out line *rowModelType: 'pagination'* then even the first page doesn't appear.
I read through the new documentation, but I couldn't find any solution for this.

Ps.: I just tried with version 7.2.2 and there this code works like a charm

Comment: Try changing `rowModelType` to `'infinite'` - if that works, i'll write an answer explaining my reasoning

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention in my question that if I change rowModelType to infinite then I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Do I miss to set a property maybe?

Comment: Hmmm... well, I do know that on [this page of the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) it says there are some changes to pagination in v9.0... I think they tried to accommodate so that they weren't **breaking** changes, but they did kind of get rid of 'pagination' as a `rowModelType`... the other suggestion I have is to remove the `rowCount: -1`, docs say it should be null if you don't know the total rowCount

Comment: Ah ye I tried that too, but it didn't help either. For me this seems to be a bug or a removed feature maybe, but the problem is that this project needs it :)